# Using Jamine to test an AngularJS service without mocks

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine

I would like to use [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/) to write tests (not unit tests) for an `AngularJS` service I have, which is a wrapper for a REST API I created on my server.  The service call should actually get all the way to the server. No mocking needed.
  I want to be able to test some scenarios involving combinations of few of these API calls.

I understand I should probably **not** be using `angular-mocks.js` but I can't figure out the syntax for getting access to the service instance in the test.

I have something like the code below. As you can see where the `??` I would like to assign the service reference to `myService` so I could use it in the tests.

```
beforeEach(function () {
  module("myApp");

  myService = ??

});
```

Also, should I include only the service file in the `specRunner.html` references list?

Comment: Have you tried just injecting it into a test? `it("", inject(function(serviceName){}))`

Comment: @Miszy Yes. But then I have to use mocks and deal with `$httpBackend`. I just want a to run the code from Jamine

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to have something like the following:

```
  $httpBackend.whenGET(/\/your-url-here-\/.*/).passThrough();
```